# PC on Domain-"you have been logged on with a default profile "

Tags: windows-7, domain

When a **ANY** user logs into this one computer that is on our domain, they get the "you have been logged on with a default profile " message.

The error occurs no matter what user with what privileges logs in. There for I have ruled out this Microsoft fix:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215

I did preform a sfc /scannow , and a chkdsk. This didn't work.  I am working remote from the PC, so I would rather not take it off the domain.

Comment: Are these users logging in for the first time or frequent users of the comptuer? This usually happens when a profile folder is corrupted/deleted and cannot be matched to their profile key in the registry as that kb shows. Have you tried creating a new profile or removing a profile/deleting the registry entry then relogging?

Comment: Remove antivirus software (temporarily) - I have seen some that locked files when windows tried to load the profile long enough that windows gave up and made a default profile

Comment: @Byron Both first time and frequent users get the same message. Now that I think about it there was an error that is now fixed but it had to do with the default profile in "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile" It was suggested from another post that I should take a users Desktop folder and put it that location. Error went away but these issues started happening. I'm going to revert the solution that caused the mention issue about.